# MySQl Репликация. Слэйв отстаёт от Мастера

Tags: mysql

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

На виртуальной машине с CentOS сделал слейв. Нагрузки на машине нет, то есть она занимается только репликацией. Слейв быстро догнал Мастер, но началось постепенное отставание, где-то по 1 секунде в сутки. При перезапуске MySQL на слейве отставание сокращается до нуля, а потом опять начинается отставание. Понятно что дело в настройках слейва.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: *началось постепенное отставание, где-то по 1 секунде в сутки* отставание чего? внутреннего таймера?

Comment: Параметр Seconds_Behind_Master из результатов команды show slave status

Comment: Первый вопрос - синхронизировано ли время между серверами? Потому как *Seconds_Behind_Master* емнип тебе показывает разницу штампов времени в пакете с мастера и обрабатывающем его потоке исполнения слейва. Вариант, что лог принят, а его обработка задерживается, и тем больше, чем больше аптайм слейва, мне кажется сомнительным.

Comment: Время синхронизировано. Насколько я понимаю разница штампов времени при перезагрузке MySQL не должна меняться.

Comment: Я 30.10 глянул, отставание секунд 10-11, рестартанул MySQL, отставание стало 0-1 секунду. 01.11 отставание стало 2-3 секунды, сегодня 12-13 секунд. Сейчас рестартанул mysql на слейве, отставание опять сократилось до 0.

Comment: Да, Вы были правы. Была неправильно настроена синхронизация времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно настроить ntp на 2-ух серверах, проблема не в mysql а в рассинхронизации времени двух серверов.

```
    yum install ntp
    chkconfig ntpd on
    ntpdate pool.ntp.org
    service ntpd start
```

В новом Centos вместо `chkconfig` нужно использовать `systemctl`

Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Спасибо, попинал админов, настроили  - теперь всё работает.